# Private methods vs calculated instance variables

Tags: python

I've had this question for a long time, and I've seen both ways being implemented. I would like to see when I would choose one over the other.

```
class Dog(object):

    def __init__(self, color, breed, data=None):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.data = data or {}

    def print_owners(self):
        owners = self._owners()

        for owner in owners:
            print(owner)

    def _owners(self):
        return self.data.get('previous_owners', [])
```

Or,

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, color, breed, data=None):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.data = data or {}
        self._owners = self.data.get('previous_owners', [])

    def print_owners(self):
        for owner in self._owners:
            print(owner)
```

```
data = {
    'dob': '05/05/2019',
    'previous_owners': ['Miguel Francisco','Juan Paulo', 'Ofelia']
}

pepito = Dog('black', 'chihuahua', data)
pepito.print_owners()
```

Both ways work, but I would like to see maybe the use cases and reasons I would pick one over the other.

I did Ruby on Rails for 2 years, and I saw the first way being implemented more often. Then, I moved to a different company where they use Python, and the second way was implemented more often. I did not like that the `__init__` method was overpopulated, but at the same time, I did not like that the over creation of methods created some sort of antipattern like behavior.

Comment: I would check [this](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) part of the docs for some of the official advice.

Comment: With the separate method, this almost works like a dynamic attribute because it gets recalculated on each call. The one in `__init__` is only set once. If you added an `@property` before the internal method, it would work like an attribute. Your implementation depends on if the data is being modified or not.

Comment: Also read through [this](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

Comment: Pythonic is really an issue of style, here, these two approaches are semantically different, so maybe the question shouldn't be about style

Comment: @NChauhan About adding the property decorator. I had the impression that you use this decorator only when trying to implement getters and setters. Owners is private, so is it good practice to add this decorator even though is not being accessed outside the class?

Comment: @Anthony Nothing in Python is ‘private’, anyone could access the name with an underscore outside of the class. Though you could say that `property` is for getters and setters, I prefer to think of it as a dynamic attribute: each time you access it, some logic is performed - in this case it retrieves data from another attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There's a visible difference between implementations if you alter the last bit of your code to:

```
data = {
    'dob': '05/05/2019',
    'previous_owners': ['Miguel Francisco','Juan Paulo', 'Ofelia']
}

pepito = Dog('black', 'chihuahua', data)
data['previous_owners'] = ['who', 'are', 'these', 'people']
pepito.print_owners()
```

In the first implementation, the words `'who'`, `'are'`, `'these'` and `'people'` are printed out.

In the second implementation, the names `'Miguel Francisco'`,`'Juan Paulo'` and `'Ofelia'` are printed out.

The difference is that the second implementation **sets the attribute `self._owners` upon initialization**, which means that the list that`data['previous_owners']` points to is associated to that instance, even if you later on delete or modify what `data['previous_owners']` points to. On the other hand, the first implementation has to **retrieve the value that  `data['previous_owners']` points to whenever the `_owners` method is called**, which means that calling `print_owners` may result in something different, depending on whether you modified the value associated with `data['previous_owners']`.

Whichever implementation is "best" depends on your specific use case: do you want that attribute to be set upon initialization (second implementation), or modify it dynamically as your code progresses (first implementation)?

Also note that in the first implementation, `_owners` is an attribute disguised as a method, so for Pythonic code what you really want is a `@property` decorator there:

```
 class Dog(object):

    def __init__(self, color, breed, data=None):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.data = data or {}

    def print_owners(self):
        for owner in self._owners:
            print(owner)

    @property
    def _owners(self):
        return self.data.get('previous_owners', [])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About adding the `@property` decorator. I had the impression that you use this decorator only when trying to implement getters and setters. Owners is private, so is it good practice to add this decorator even though is not being accessed outside the class?